# Installing Ubuntu to external HD - Mount/Unmount?

Tags: mount, unmount

Hello Everyone,
                  I wish to install ubuntu to my External USB Hard Drive. When I choose the something else option, the installer detects both my internal drive (SDA) and my External drive (SDB). The installer wants me to unmount both of them but unmounting SDA drive is dangerous? I have read articles stating that you must disconnect SDA first. I don't want to touch the SDA drive. Is there another way to install ubuntu to the external drive? If I unmount SDA, will that not cause the internal drive to fail to boot to windows?

Answer (score 0):

> unmounting SDA drive is dangerous?

Unmounting makes that drive inaccessible for read or write operations. It is a Linux only feature, so Windows drives are not affected by it.

> I don't want to touch the SDA drive.

If it is unmounted during the installation then it won't be touched. However, if you choose to write the bootloader on it or make any other operations to it, it will be automatically mounted!

> If I unmount SDA, will that not cause the internal drive to fail to boot to windows?

No. This has nothing to do with Windows.

When installing Ubuntu on an external drive, the location of the bootloader is of interest.

- If you install the bootloader on the internal drive (`sda`), then no matter if external is not plugged in, you will have an option to boot Ubuntu when you start up your computer. If you choose it, it will give an error. Choosing Windows will boot into Windows.
- If you install the bootloader on the external drive (`sdb`), nothing will be modified on Windows drive. No menu to choose OS will appear. If you plug in your external drive, your computer will boot into Ubuntu from it only if it is set as the first drive in your BIOS settings. Otherwise it will boot into Windows.

Answer (score 0):

When you boot the install disk, you Windows drive was most likely mounted (or you mounted it).  Mounting means that Ubuntu will be able to read or write files to it.  Since it is your Windows partition, it is actually more dangerous to have it mounted than unmounted, because unmounted you can't write to it, mounted you can accidentally mess things up.

When you unmount a drive on Ubuntu, it does not affect the data on it in any way, so you are perfectly safe unmounting it.

It sounds like you are new to this, so be carefully when choosing "Something Else" in installation.

I will give you two ways to do what you are trying to achieve:

**Easy Way/Safest Way**
To be Totally safe, shut you computer down, get out a screw driver and remove the Windows hard drive.  Boot Ubuntu Installation Disk with you external drive plugged in.  Now you have absolutely no worries!  Keep in mind that your external drive will be sda in this case when you physically remove your Windows drive.

**Advanced Way / Risky If You Don't Follow Exactly!**

1. When asked to "Unmount partitions that are in use?", answer yes.
2. Look in the device column.  You will see sdb.  That's just the name of the device.  Make damn sure sdb is your external.  A device may or may not have partitions.  Partitions divide the physical device up with names like, sdb1, sdb2.  Choose a partition on /dev/sdb. By choosing, I mean click on it so that it is highlighted.

*If no partition exists, I would suggest exiting and using gparted to make an ext4 partition then come back to this point. (The partition will need to be probably 5 gig or bigger, don't remember exactly.)*

1. Now that you have the partition on the device sdb selected you want to install to, press the change button.
2. A window will appear.  In the "Use As", combo box, select Ext4 journal file system.  Check the format check button.  Then, in the "Mount Point" combo box, select the "/" symbol.
3. DANGER HERE:  You said you don't want your windows drive touched?  Ok, where it says "Device for boot loader installation", there is a combo box.  It most likely has /dev/sda selected, which would be your Windows drive.  Change that to /dev/sdb.
4. Double check everything has been done exactly or if you don't understand for some reason some step, just quit and come back here with further questions.  If you feel you have followed everything exactly, then proceed by pressing the "Install Now" button.
5. You may be asked about swap, it's optional.  Just don't create one on you Windows device /dev/sda

For you I would personally suggest unplugging the Windows drive, but live and learn.